# How do I get topIndex to hold 52 cards?

Tags: java, blackjack

So this is for a game called BackJAck and when it calls for to getCard my topIndex is at zero so it is trying to get a card but there are no cards to get. I need it to start at 52. Can anyone help me please?

```
public class Deck {

public static final int NUM_FACES = 13;
public static final int NUM_SUITS = 4;
public static final int NUM_CARDS = NUM_FACES * NUM_SUITS;

public static final String[] SUITS = { "Clubs", "Spades", "Diamonds", "Hearts" };

private AbstractCard[] deck;

private int topIndex=0;


public Deck() {
    // Instantiate deck and fill it with cards. 
    deck = new AbstractCard[52];
    int cnt = 0;
    AbstractCard[] card = new AbstractCard[0];
    for ( int v = 1; v <= NUM_FACES; v++) {
        for ( int u = 0; u < NUM_SUITS; u++) {
            deck[cnt] = new BlackJackCard(v , SUITS[u]   );
            cnt++;
        }



    }


}

public void shuffle() {
    topIndex=0;
   for( int i = 0 ; i < 100; i++ ){
       int x = (int) Math.random()*51; 
       int y= (int) Math.random() *51;
       if ( x != y ){
           AbstractCard card1 = deck[x];
       deck[x] = deck[y];
       deck[y] = card1;
       }
   }



}

public AbstractCard getCard() {
    return deck[topIndex++];
}

public int cardsLeft() {
    return 52 - topIndex; 
}

public boolean hasCards() {
    return topIndex<51;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say because you don't give us your Card classes or any example calls to the `Deck` class (i.e. *how* you're using `Deck`).

I'm assuming `BlackJackCard` extends `AbstractCard` and just stores the card value and suit.

I created a simple `BlackJackCard` class myself, and it appears your `Deck` constructor does populate your deck array with `BlackJackCard`s.

And `getCard()` will return a `BlackJackCard` from the deck array then increment `topIndex`.

Running something like

```
Deck deck = new Deck();
deck.shuffle();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println(deck.getCard().toString());
}
```

Should give a result similar to this (formatting, etc. may vary):

```
(Diamonds, 11)
(Clubs, 2)
(Diamonds, 3)
(Hearts, 1)
(Diamonds, 2)
```

If you want to start at card 52 instead of card 0, I suppose you could change `topIndex` to 52 and decrement inside of `getCard()` *instead* of incrementing. You'd also need to change the logic of `cardsLeft()` and `hasCards()`.

So it looks like `Deck` creates the cards. And it looks like `getCard()` will return a card from your "deck". If you want to start at card 52 instead of 0, you might change your method logic. But if your issue is that you're not getting any cards from `Deck` - you'd need to provide information about *how* you're using `Deck`.

I noticed a couple of other things too.

`(int) Math.random()*51` will always return 0. The `(int)` cast applies to `Math.random()` first, which will result in 0. So your `shuffle()` method doesn't actually shuffle anything.
You probably meant `(int) (Math.random() * 51)` which will multiple the random, *then* cast to an int.

You use 51/52 throughout your code. You define `NUM_CARDS`, might be good to use it instead of hard-coding in the value.

The `AbstractCard[] card = new AbstractCard[0];` in your constructor is unused.